# adding jar files to the project in netbeans

Tags: slick2d, java

I downloaded latests version of java slick 2D library and LWJGL, but I'm in dilemma which files to chose. I've found those tutorials on YT on how to add libraries but they're old like 3 years. Also, is there any way to implement library just like we currently use SDK, with out adding this jar files each time to diff projects ?

Answer (score 0):

You can define a folder in netbeans that will be responsible for storing all jar files, instead of adding the jar files one by one.